# C - How to allocate memory for a linked list inside a struct

Tags: c

I simply wish to create a deck of cards when newGame is called. How do I insert card values into linked list drawPile (which is inside the game struct)? I'm asked to implement this ADT, so please don't add functions. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
typedef enum {RED,BLACK} color;
typedef enum {HEARTS,DIAMONDS,CLUBS,SPADES} suit;
typedef enum {ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR} value;

typedef struct _card { //struct of cards
    color color;
    suit suit;
    value value;
}card;

typedef struct _drawPile{ //drawPile linked list
    card *card;
    struct _drawPile *next;
}drawPile;

//game struct to store the state of the game.e.g. what cards are in the drawPile.
typedef struct _game{ 
    struct drawPile *game_drawPile;
}*Game;

//creates a deck of cards when called(with specific cards passed in parameters,example of main below)
Game newGame(int deckSize, value values[], color colors[], suit suits[]){

    for(int i = 0;i < deckSize; i++){
        Game nGame = malloc(sizeof(Game));
//this gives me a compile error, 
//how should i allocate memory for drawPile inside my nGame struct?
        nGame->game_drawPile->card->color = colors[i];
        nGame->game_drawPile->card->suit = suits[i];
        nGame->game_drawPile->card->value = values[i];
        nGame->game_drawPile = nGame->game_drawPile->next;
    }
        return nGame;
}
```

below is an example main function of how the newGame function is going to run with only 4 cards.

```
int main (void){

     init_deck();

}
static void init_deck(void){
    int deck_size = 4;

    value values[] = {ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR};
    color colors[] = {RED, BLACK, RED, BLACK};
    suit suits[] = {HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES};

    Game game = newGame(deck_size, values, colors, suits);
 }
```

Comment: How does your `newGame()` know the size of `values`, `colors` and `suits`?

Comment: `Game nGame = malloc(sizeof(Game));`...  malloc returns a pointer... `Game *nGame = malloc(sizeof(Game));`

Comment: @Swordfish an example of main function is below, the specific cards will be given.

Comment: @GradyPlayer `Game` is a `typedef struct _game * Game`

Comment: Can there be less or more than 4 `values`, `colors` and `suits`?

Comment: @Swordfish, oh you are right... missed that.

Comment: @Swordfish yes it can that is up to the user of newGame

Comment: so that should then be `malloc(sizeof(*Game));`

Comment: Then the user of `newGame()` must pass the number of `values`, `colors` and `suits` to the function and it needs additional parameters.

Comment: @GradyPlayer Yes, even better: `malloc(sizeof(*nGame));` ;p Another example why one should not do such `typedef`s for pointers. (Or at least call it `pCard` ... even if I hate hungarian.)

Comment: @Swordfish there is an int of deck size passed in

Comment: @GradyPlayer will that be enough memory allocation for this problem? I'm getting error "incomplete definition of type 'struct drawPile"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum { RED, BLACK } color;
char const * color_names[] = { "RED", "BLACK" };

typedef enum { HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES } suit;
char const * suit_names[] = { "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS", "SPADES" };

typedef enum { ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR } value;
char const * value_names[] = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR" };


typedef struct _card {
    color color;
    suit suit;
    value value;
} card;

typedef struct _drawPile {
    card *card;
    struct _drawPile *next;
} drawPile;

typedef struct _game {
    int deckSize;
    drawPile *game_drawPile;
} *Game;

Game newGame(int deckSize, value values[], color colors[], suit suits[])
{
    Game nGame = malloc(sizeof(*nGame));
    nGame->game_drawPile = NULL;
    nGame->deckSize = deckSize;
    suit s = 0;
    color c = 0;
    value v = 0;
    int const num_cards = deckSize * deckSize * deckSize;
    int const cards_per_suit = deckSize * deckSize;
    drawPile *current = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_cards; i++)
    {
        if (!nGame->game_drawPile) {
            nGame->game_drawPile = malloc(sizeof(drawPile));
            nGame->game_drawPile->next = NULL;
            nGame->game_drawPile->card = malloc(sizeof(card));
            nGame->game_drawPile->card->suit = s;
            nGame->game_drawPile->card->color = c;
            nGame->game_drawPile->card->value = v;
            current = nGame->game_drawPile;
        }
        else {
            current->next = malloc(sizeof(drawPile));
            current = current->next;
            current->next = NULL;
            current->card = malloc(sizeof(card));
            current->card->suit = s;
            current->card->color = c;
            current->card->value = v;
        }

        if ((i + 1) % cards_per_suit == 0) ++s;
        if (s % cards_per_suit == 0) s = 0;

        if ((i + 1) % deckSize == 0) ++c;
        if (c % deckSize == 0) c = 0;

        ++v;
        if (v % deckSize == 0) v = 0;
    }
    return nGame;
}

void printCard(card *c)
{
    printf("%s %s %s\n", suit_names[c->suit], color_names[c->color], value_names[c->value]);
}

void printGame(Game game)
{
    for (drawPile *current = game->game_drawPile; current; current = current->next)
        printCard(current->card);
}

void destroyGame(Game game)
{
    for (drawPile *current = game->game_drawPile, *temp; current; current = temp) {
        temp = current->next;
        free(current->card);
        free(current);
        current = temp;
    }
    free(game);
}

void init_deck(void)
{
    int deck_size = 4;
    value values[] = { ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR };
    color colors[] = { RED, BLACK, RED, BLACK };
    suit  suits [] = { HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES };

    Game game = newGame(deck_size, values, colors, suits);
    printGame(game);
    destroyGame(game);
}

int main(void)
{
    init_deck();
}
```

#### Output:

```
HEARTS RED ONE
HEARTS RED TWO
HEARTS RED THREE
HEARTS RED FOUR
HEARTS BLACK ONE
HEARTS BLACK TWO
HEARTS BLACK THREE
HEARTS BLACK FOUR
HEARTS HEARTS ONE
HEARTS HEARTS TWO
HEARTS HEARTS THREE
HEARTS HEARTS FOUR
HEARTS DIAMONDS ONE
HEARTS DIAMONDS TWO
HEARTS DIAMONDS THREE
HEARTS DIAMONDS FOUR
DIAMONDS RED ONE
DIAMONDS RED TWO
DIAMONDS RED THREE
DIAMONDS RED FOUR
DIAMONDS BLACK ONE
DIAMONDS BLACK TWO
DIAMONDS BLACK THREE
DIAMONDS BLACK FOUR
DIAMONDS HEARTS ONE
DIAMONDS HEARTS TWO
DIAMONDS HEARTS THREE
DIAMONDS HEARTS FOUR
DIAMONDS DIAMONDS ONE
DIAMONDS DIAMONDS TWO
DIAMONDS DIAMONDS THREE
DIAMONDS DIAMONDS FOUR
CLUBS RED ONE
CLUBS RED TWO
CLUBS RED THREE
CLUBS RED FOUR
CLUBS BLACK ONE
CLUBS BLACK TWO
CLUBS BLACK THREE
CLUBS BLACK FOUR
CLUBS HEARTS ONE
CLUBS HEARTS TWO
CLUBS HEARTS THREE
CLUBS HEARTS FOUR
CLUBS DIAMONDS ONE
CLUBS DIAMONDS TWO
CLUBS DIAMONDS THREE
CLUBS DIAMONDS FOUR
SPADES RED ONE
SPADES RED TWO
SPADES RED THREE
SPADES RED FOUR
SPADES BLACK ONE
SPADES BLACK TWO
SPADES BLACK THREE
SPADES BLACK FOUR
SPADES HEARTS ONE
SPADES HEARTS TWO
SPADES HEARTS THREE
SPADES HEARTS FOUR
SPADES DIAMONDS ONE
SPADES DIAMONDS TWO
SPADES DIAMONDS THREE
SPADES DIAMONDS FOUR
```

> in my example main, there would only be 4 cards. (one red hearts, two black diamonds etc.)

Then passing `values`, `colors` and `suits` has no merit whatsoever.

```
Game newGame(int deckSize)
{
    Game nGame = malloc(sizeof(*nGame));
    nGame->game_drawPile = NULL;
    nGame->deckSize = deckSize;
    drawPile *current = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < deckSize; i++)
    {
        if (!nGame->game_drawPile) {
            nGame->game_drawPile = malloc(sizeof(drawPile));
            nGame->game_drawPile->next = NULL;
            nGame->game_drawPile->card = malloc(sizeof(card));
            nGame->game_drawPile->card->suit  = suits[i];
            nGame->game_drawPile->card->color = colors[i];
            nGame->game_drawPile->card->value = values[i];
            current = nGame->game_drawPile;
        }
        else {
            current->next = malloc(sizeof(drawPile));
            current = current->next;
            current->next = NULL;
            current->card = malloc(sizeof(card));
            current->card->suit  = suits[i];
            current->card->color = colors[i];
            current->card->value = values[i];
        }
    }
    return nGame;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this! Much appreciated, though what we are required is more simple, e.g. in my example main, there would only be 4 cards. (one red hearts, two black diamonds etc.) :) thanks for your time.

Comment: thx but thats the format I have to use, the user of newGame will decide each and every specific card to be present in the deck

Comment: What is the point of passing `suits`, `colors` and `values` to the function when the result only depends on `deckSize`? ("there would only be 4 cards. (one red hearts, two black diamonds etc.)")

Comment: sorry, what i meant was: one red hearts, two black diamonds, three red clubs, four black spades, are 4 consecutive cards given by the 3 arrays: value, color, suit. deckSize is also given to us just to make life easier I guess. Decks are formed based on the 3 arrays. e.g. if I want a deck with  50 cards, i have to fill the 3 arrays each with 50 values

Comment: "what i meant was: one red hearts, two black diamonds, three red clubs, four black spades, are 4 consecutive cards" Yes, I got that. "given by the 3 arrays" nope. The arrays have nothing to do with it. See the last code snippet in my answer. " e.g. if I want a deck with 50 cards" you simply set `deckSize` to `50`.

Comment: e.g. if I want a deck with 50 cards of all HEARTS RED ONE, I could do that by writing 50 times of HEARTS in suits[], 50 times of RED in colors[] and 50 times of ONE in values[];

Comment: Now I see. Changed the last snipped.

Comment: really appreciate your time. im new to C, pointers often confuses me

Answer (score 1):

you can't declare `game` in the `for` loop and reference it outside:

```
    Game nGame;
    for(int i = 0;i < deckSize; i++){
        nGame = malloc(sizeof(Game));
        nGame->game_drawPile->card->color = colors[i];
        nGame->game_drawPile->card->suit = suits[i];
        nGame->game_drawPile->card->value = values[i];
        nGame->game_drawPile = nGame->game_drawPile->next;
    }
    return nGame;
```

also, because you have used a `typedef`, you have to refer to `drawPile` without a preceding `struct` keyword:

```
typedef struct _game{ 
    drawPile *game_drawPile;
}*Game;
```